# Entity Framework Core returning object with many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure how to get the information I need using EF Core with a .NET Core app. I have two database tables - OBJECTS and TAGS with a many-to-many relationship (using a third join table OBJECTTAGS). I want to get all the objects (about 1400) along with their associated tags.

These are my three models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ContentMarketplace.Models
{
    public partial class Object
    {
        public int ObjectId { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual List<ObjectTag> ObjectTags { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ContentMarketplace.Models
{
    public partial class Tag
    {
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual List<ObjectTag> ObjectTags { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ContentMarketplace.Models
{
    public partial class ObjectTag
    {
        public int ObjectId { get; set; }
        public virtual Object Object { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is what's in the OnModelCreating() method in my context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectTag>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ObjectId, e.TagId });

    entity.HasOne(ot => ot.Object)
        .WithMany(o => o.ObjectTags)
        .HasForeignKey(ot => ot.ObjectId);

    entity.HasOne(ot => ot.Tag)
        .WithMany(t => t.ObjectTags)
        .HasForeignKey(ot => ot.TagId);
});
```

This issue arises when I try to return data in my ObjectController.cs

```
namespace ContentMarketplace.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ObjectController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ContentMarketplaceContext _context;

        public ObjectController(ContentMarketplaceContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }       

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<ContentMarketplace.Models.Object>> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Objects
                .Include(o => o.ObjectTags)
                .ThenInclude(ot => ot.Tag)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The Include().ThenInclude() creates a circular relationship where an HTTP request doesn't just return the tag information associated with each object but then all the objects associated with each of those tags and so on, crashing the browser.

If I take out the ThenInclude() it works fine but doesn't return all the tag info not in my ObjectTag model.

I know this has to do with EF Core auto loading stuff that's already in the context (like the "tip" notes here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) but I don't know how else to return JUST the object and tags without going any further.

Comment: Is the error coming from the JSON serializer or from EF Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Include` or `Theninclude` in your query it will create circular references. JSON cannot handle circular reference. You can easily overcome this problem using `Select` query.

**Without DTO:**

Write your `GetAll()` controller-method as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var objectList =  _context.Objects.Select(o => new
            {
               o.ObjectId,
               Tags = o.ObjectTags.Select(ot => ot.Tag).ToList()
            }).ToList();

     return Ok(objectList);
}
```

**With DTO:**

Write your DTO class as follows:

```
public class ObjectDto
{
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    ....
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `GetAll()` controller-method should be as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<ObjectDto>> GetAll()
{
    var objectList =  _context.Objects.Select(o => new ObjectDto
            {
               ObjectId = o.ObjectId,
               Tags = o.ObjectTags.Select(ot => ot.Tag).ToList()
            }).ToList();

     return objectList;
}
```

**Note: If you use `Select` inside your query you don't need to use `Include` or `Theninclude`.**

Hope it will now work as expected!

Comment: JSON can handle circular references.  You need to configure it to ignore them. See @TaoZhou's answer.

Comment: @Brad but you have specify up-to a certain hierarchy otherwise your browser will crush. Moreover if you use `Select` you don't even need to use Include and  set additional settings to ignore Reference Loop.

Comment: The Select statement way worked but is there a simpler way to do it, say using Mapster/AutoMapper? Manually populating the DTO is a bit tedious.

Comment: @blankface AutoMapper is bad thing to use. Even the author of AutoMapper says that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: @zoran, Could you please give me the link?

Comment: @TanvirArjel 
https://twitter.com/jbogard/status/1100394639155253250?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw
"no one should use AutoMapper!"

https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/
"AutoMapper was built to address snowflake DTOs" ""DO NOT" use AutoMapper unless you buy in to the reasons why it was made in the first place"

Comment: @TanvirArjel 
Here are some additional links about AutoMapper explaining how it was made for specific cases only:
https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/
https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/

Comment: Great explanation, thank you for taking the time to answer this.  I have a very similar design type quest and I never though of filtering the object list.  thanks again.  I've been at this for about a week. smh... and btw @TanvirArjel great nuget package on generic repos. nice work. (i've used it) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by the loop reference, you could try to below to ignore the loop reference.

```
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(opt => {
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });
```

For another option, you could try to return `ObjectModel` with `List<Tag>` directly instead of `List<ObjectTag>`

`ObjectModel`

```
    public partial class ObjectModel
{
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Query

```
        public List<Models.ObjectModel> GetAll()
    {
        //return _db.Object
        //    .Include(o => o.ObjectTags)
        //    .ThenInclude(ot => ot.Tag)
        //    .ToList();
        return _db.Object
            .Include(o => o.ObjectTags)
            .ThenInclude(ot => ot.Tag)
            .Select(r => new Models.ObjectModel
            {
                ObjectId = r.ObjectId,
                Name = r.Name,
                Tags = r.ObjectTags.Select(ot => ot.Tag).ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
    }
```